# Regex for matching "non-javadoc" comment in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, javadoc, replace, multiline

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches the `(non-javadoc)` comments in the format

```
/*
 * (non-javadoc)
 *
 * some other comment here
 *
 */
```

So far I have `(?s)/\*\R.*?non-Javadoc.*?\*/`, but that is actually matching too much. I have a header at the top of my file that is something like

```
/*
 * header text
 */
 public class MyClass {

 }
```

and it is matching the `/*` at the top of the file, but I really only want to match the generated `(non-javadoc)` comment. Can anyone help me fix up this regex?

EDIT: I'm trying to use the Eclipse Find/Replace dialog, but I am open to using external tools if needed.

Comment: Don't know, which language that is, but it may be PHP and in this case, use the Tokenizer.

Comment: @KingCrunch, it is using the Eclipse find/replace

Comment: (+1) for the question, as I am also just hunting down those ugly zero-information code-rubbish in Eclipse... :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(?s)/\*[^*](?:(?!\*/).)*\(non-javadoc\)(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/
```

`/\*[^*]` matches the beginning of a C-style comment (`/* */`) but not a JavaDoc comment (`/** */`)

`(?!\*/).` matches any single character unless it's the beginning of a `*/` sequence.  Searching for `(?:(?!\*/).)*` instead of `.*?` makes it impossible for a match to start in one comment and end in another.

**UPDATE:** In (belated) response to the comment by Jacek: yes, you'll probably want to add something to the end of the regex so you can replace it with an empty string and not leave a lot of blank lines in your code.  But Jacek's solution is more complicated than it needs to be.  All you need to add is `\s*`

The `\R` escape sequence matches many kinds of newline, including the Unicode Line Separator (`\u2028`) and Paragraph Separator (`\u2029`) and the DOS/network carriage-return+linefeed sequence (`\r\n`).  But those are all whitespace characters, so `\s` matches them (in Eclipse, at least; according to [the docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), it's equivalent to `[\t\n\f\r\p{Z}]`).

The `\s*` in Jacek's addition was only meant to match whatever horizontal whitespace (spaces or tabs) might exist *before* the newline, plus the indentation following it.  (You have to remove it because you're *not* removing the indentation before the first line of the comment.)  But it turns out `\s*` can do the whole job:

```
(?s)/\*[^*](?:(?!\*/).)*\(non-javadoc\)(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/\s*
```

Comment: It would be also good to add `(\s*)\R(\s*)` at the end of the above regular expression to include the following line break and indentation characters. Otherwise a replacement with empty string will leave an empty line in place of each comment.

Comment: Someone felt strongly enough about this to edit Jacek's addition into my regex.  My thanks to the reviewers who rejected that edit, and thank you, @Tom, for bringing this incomplete answer back to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, it would look like

```
/
   \/\*
   (?: (?! \*\/ ) . )*
   non-javadoc
   (?: (?! \*\/ ) . )*
   \*\/
/sx
```

Comment: I should have specified it is using the Eclipse find/replace